# On relatively compact sets in the space of holomorphic functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, compactness, locally-convex-spaces

I'm having trouble with an exercise about holomorhpic functions. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open convex set and let $F \subset H(\Omega)$ be a relatively compact set in the open-compact topology. Show that $F'=\{f':f \in F\}$ is relatively compact. Give a counter example that the reciprocal is not true and give an additional condition to ensure that if $F'$ is relatively compact then $F$ is relatively compact.

I tried using sequentially compactness of $F$ to prove sequentially compactness of $F'$, but I asked my professor and he said that we don't know if $H(\Omega)$ is sequentially compact. He told me that I should try using Ascoli-Arzelá Theorem, but I need uniform boundedness of $F'$ and I don't know how to prove that.

I have the counterexample for the second part,I defined $F=\{f_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with $f_n(z)=n$, so that $F'=\{0\}$ that is compact but $F$ is not pointwise bounded, so by Ascoli-Arzlá Theorem it can't be relatively compact. But I have no clue in what condition should I give to have the recyprocal.

Can anyone help me or give me a hint on how to do this exercise?

Comment: The formula $$f'(z)={1\over 2\pi i}\int\limits_C{f(u)\over (u-z)^2}\,du$$ for a simple closed curve around $z$ may help.

Comment: Differentiation $H(\Omega)\to H(\Omega)$ is a linear continuous map (you just need that this map has in fact values in the Fréchet space $H(\Omega)$ -- which follows, e.g., from the Cauchy integral formula for circles, continuity then follows from the closed graph theorem without using global versions of the integral formula). Since relatively compact sets are contained in compact sets (which is or should be the definition) you just use that continuous images of compact sets are compact.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the differentiation map has values in $H(\Omega)$? Because in $\Omega$ I can differentiate $f$ as much as I want, or I'm missing something?